# Docker multi-stage ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm building my first Docker multi-staged project (to reduce size of the image) following this tutorial: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/.

My dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
      python3 python3-pip python3-venv

RUN python3 -m venv /opt/fwr

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3-alpine3.18 AS build-image

WORKDIR /opt/fwr

COPY --from=compile-image /opt/fwr /opt/fwr

COPY *.py ./

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

CMD ["-u", "main.py"] 

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

All stages are going well, but once I try tu ryn container I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/fwr/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

The question is: What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a different base image for compiling than you are in the final image. Your Dockerfile as shown isn't valid -- it's missing the initial `FROM` line -- but it looks like you're probably using an Ubuntu variant.

Ubuntu -- and most other Linux distributions -- are built around the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) C library. Alpine, in order to reduce the size of the distribution, uses [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/). When you build something under Ubuntu, it is very common for it to fail to run under Alpine because the two environments use different dynamic loaders.

If you use the same base image for compiling things that you use in your final image, you'll find that things build and run as expected:

```
FROM python:3-alpine3.18 AS compile-image

RUN apk add alpine-sdk gfortran
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/fwr

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3-alpine3.18 AS build-image

WORKDIR /opt/fwr

COPY --from=compile-image /opt/fwr /opt/fwr

COPY *.py ./

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

CMD ["-u", "main.py"] 

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

NB: Pandas doesn't provide binary wheels for Alpine, so everything needs to be built from source. That can take a **long** time. Because optimizing for size is often a wasted effort, you can substantially improve your build time if you just use the standard Python image instead:

```
FROM python:3

RUN python3 -m venv /opt/fwr
WORKDIR /opt/fwr

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY *.py ./

ENV PATH="/opt/fwr/bin:$PATH"

CMD ["-u", "main.py"] 

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

Since we're not actually compiling anything here, we can use a single stage image. Total build time is maybe a minute (probably faster if that alpine build wasn't **still running** in other terminal).

**Update**

The alpine build finally finished; the final image sizes are:

```
pytest-alpine   341 MB
pytest-debian   1.15 GB
```

You might think, "wow, the Debian-based image is so much bigger!", but in practice, because you will often have many images built from the same base, the real size impact is minimal.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! Indeed I just didn't copied first line, and you're right that I used debian based image at first stage (as I had problems to compile Pandas in alpine). Now I do understand much, much more.